# Doubt about Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, measurable-functions

I am doing Measure theory from the book by p.k jain .
The definition of Measurable function is given that: An extended real valued function defined on a measurable set E is said to be measurable if the set of those x in E for which f(x) > a (for all real a) is measurable.I am stuck  In the proof ' A continuous function defined on a measurable set is measurable .' I know that inverse image of an open set is open under a continuous function .In the book it is proved that the set { x in E : f(x) > a } is open being the inverse image of an open set ( a , b) ,b= infinity.

My question is that to show that f is measurable ,one should prove that { x in E : f(x) > a} is measurable being the inverse image of (a ,b] , b = infinity .Why the extended real number line is ignored here .
Is (a, b] ,b= infinity is open in extended real number line?

Comment: Continuous functions are real valued.

Comment: For an extended real valued function , What should be the inverse image of { x : f(x) > a} ? Is it (a, infinity) or (a , infinity]

Comment: You have to include $\infty$ also.

Comment: This is my doubt ,why it is not included in the book ,and if we include this then how to prove further

Comment: Please use MathJax for formulas, even if they are quite simple. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Sets of the form $(a,\infty ]$ are open in the standard topology of the extended real line. Also the order in the extended real line is given such that $a< \infty $ for all $a\in[-\infty ,\infty )$, therefore

$$
\{x\in \Omega : f(x)>a\}=\begin{cases}
f^{-1}((a,\infty]),& a<\infty \\
\emptyset ,& a=\infty 
\end{cases}
$$

To show that $f$ is measurable it is enough to show that $f^{-1}((a,\infty ])$ is measurable for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$ because

$$
f^{-1}(\infty )=f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(n,\infty ]\right)=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}f^{-1}((n,\infty ])\\
f^{-1}(-\infty )=f^{-1}\left(\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}(n,\infty ]\right)^\complement \right)=\left(f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}(n,\infty ]\right)\right)^\complement =\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}f^{-1}((n,\infty ])\right)^\complement 
$$

therefore $f^{-1}(\infty )$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty )$ are measurable if all $f^{-1}((a,\infty ])$, with $a\in \mathbb{R}$, are measurable.